# Set variable point size in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to set a **variable** marker size in a scatter plot. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from os import getcwd
from os.path import join, realpath, dirname

mypath = realpath(join(getcwd(), dirname(__file__)))
myfile = 'b34.dat'

data = np.loadtxt(join(mypath,myfile),
     usecols=(1,2,3),
     unpack=True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(data[0], data[1], 'bo', markersize=data[2], label='the data')
plt.show()
```

The file I'm importing has three columns. Columns 1 and 2 are stored in `data[0]` and `data[1]`) are the `(x,y)` values and I want each point to have a size relative to column 3 (ie: `data[2]`)

I'm using the [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) IDE by the way.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`help(plt.plot)` shows

```
  markersize or ms: float
```

so it appears `plt.plot` does not allow the markersize to be an array.

You could use `plt.scatter` however:

```
ax1.scatter(data[0], data[1], marker='o', c='b', s=data[2], label='the data')
```

---

PS. You can also verify that `plt.plot`'s `markersize` must be a float by searching for "markersize" in [the official documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).